# conky keeps grabbing focus and shortcuts and desktop switching does not work

Tags: compiz, conky

I run into this issue recently when I tried to use Conky with Compiz & Unity on Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I close some application I am focused to Conky and can't use shortcuts or switch desktops. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I don't know if you or others are interested but I use ***Unity Tweak Tool*** for high DPI scaling and there are no problems with ***Conky*** interrupting the flow of other applications or shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Install Compiz configuration manager and compiz plugins:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

now open compiz manager and enable window rules plugin:

[image: compiz manager]

and and add class=Conky to No focus line:

[image]

now simply set window class in conky:

```
own_window_class = 'Conky',
```

and log-off and log in again.

my whole Conky window setup:

```
own_window_class = 'Conky',
own_window_argb_visual = true,
own_window_argb_value=0,
own_window_type='dock',
own_window=true,
own_window_transparent=true,
own_window_hints='undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
```